# validation script for Gravity Forms that can detect the presence of the number 1 or +1 in the first position of the telephone number

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am a designer and not much a coder person. here is my problem

I need a validation script for Gravity Forms that can detect the presence of the number 1 or +1 in the first position of the telephone number and then return an error and present the following message:

Please use the following format.  DO NOT add a 1 in front of the phone number.
XXX-XXX-XXXX

I found this phone validation script, but need to edit it for the rule above.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', 'validate_phone', 10, 4 );
function validate_phone( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $pattern = "/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)|\(?01\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/";
    if ( $field->type == 'phone' && $field->phoneFormat != 'standard' && ! preg_match( $pattern, $value ) ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'Please enter a valid phone number';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script you can use to address the rules you outlined above.  This will only allow a form to be submitted that does not have a 1 in the first position.  It also requires that the phone field contain no more AND no less than 10 digits, and it will error out if any characters entered are not a number.  Hope this helps.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', 'validate_phone', 10, 4 );
function validate_phone( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
 $pattern = "/^(?!1)[0-9]{10}$/";
 if ( $field->type == 'phone' && !preg_match( $pattern, $value ) ) {
  $result['is_valid'] = false;
  $result['message']  = 'Please enter your phone number in the following format: 2125551212';
 }

 return $result;
}
```